# How to change to temp directory in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, temp

In PowerShell I can echo the value of `%TEMP%` using the command `$Env:TEMP`. Here is the output on my machine:

```
PS> $Env:temp
C:\Users\IAIN~1.COR\AppData\Local\Temp
```

When I try to change to the directory using the `cd` command, I receive this error:

```
PS> cd $Env:temp
Set-Location : An object at the specified path C:\Users\IAIN~1.COR does not exist.
At line:1 char:3
+ cd <<<<  $Env:temp
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I suspect that PowerShell is interpreting the 8.3 file name literally. The long file name of the directory is `C:\Users\iain.CORP\AppData\Local\Temp`. When I try `cd C:\Users\Iain.CORP\AppData\Local\Temp`, the directory changes successfully.

How can I open the path in `$Env:TEMP` using PowerShell? Do I have to have the long file name first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to access the `%TEMP%` environment variable directly.

.NET provides a `GetTempPath` method as a more general solution.

```
$TempDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
cd $TempDir
```

On my machine, this changes to the directory `C:\Users\Iain.CORP\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Remarks from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx):

> This method checks for the existence of environment variables in the
>   following order and uses the first path found:
>
> 1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> 2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> 3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
> 4. The Windows directory.

Thanks to [Joe Angley](http://joelangley.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/temp-directory-in-powershell.html) for sharing the technique.

Answer (score 9):

Open `$env:temp` by first resolving its fullname like this:

```
cd (gi $env:temp).fullname
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. In the end I decided to use [the .NET method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783291/111424) because it is more robust than relying on one environment variable. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 8):

`cd $env:temp`

This worked for me.

Comment: This fails in my environment, as I demonstrated in the question. What does it return in yours? I think this method will fail in an environment in which `$Env:TEMP` returns an [8.3 File Name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982) rather than the Long File Name.